# Time Series Decomposition on a few months of data?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to decompose my data to see what the trend and seasonality effects are. I have 4 months of data, recorded daily. Data looks like:

```
date    amount
11/1/2000   1700
11/2/2000   11087
11/3/2000   11248
11/4/2000   13336
11/5/2000   18815
11/6/2000   8820
11/7/2000   7687
11/8/2000   5514
11/9/2000   9591
11/10/2000  9676
11/11/2000  14782
11/12/2000  18554
```

And so forth to the end of Feb 2001. I read in the data like so and generate a timeseries object:

```
myvector <- read.table("clipboard", sep="\t", header=T)
myts <- ts(myvector$amount, start=c(2000,11), frequency=52)
```

I'm very confused as to how to read this data in as a time series object. The data is recorded daily, but if I use `frequency=365`, then try

```
fit <- stl(myts2, s.window="periodic")
```

I get:
    `Error in stl(myts2, s.window = "periodic") : 
      series is not periodic or has less than two periods`

Every example I find does the object casting with multiple years worth of data. Is this not possible in my case?

I know the next steps for plotting the trend and decomposition are:

```
fit <- stl(myts, s.window="periodic")
plot(fit)
```

Comment: Odd. I can't treat months as individual periods? It always has to be yearly?

Comment: Specify the `s.window` to a month-ish number of lags. The option periodic is based on the frequency. The problem will be that months have an irregular number of days. Its generally odd to think of intramonthly seasonality unless, e.g. you are looking at effects of paychecks on the 1st and 15th of each month. But perhaps you are looking for weekly trends?

Comment: Weekly trends would be interesting. Would I set frequency=120 for the total number of observations, then set s.window=30 for a more-or-less monthly bin range?

Comment: Let's take weekly. You can specify the `ts` object to have frequency 7. Then the daily observations, including the `start` argument, would be interpreted as (week number, day of week number) and you could use `stl`'s periodic argument. If you specify the `ts` with frequency 365, then you are interpreting the the observations as (year number, day of year number), and you'd want to not want periodic for `stl`, as doing so is trying to find seasonal trends over the yearly. frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Try [seasonal differencing](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/1), which is similar to regular differencing except is applied over different periods:

[image]

An example:

```
data(austres)

plot(austres)
```

[image]

```
seasonal <- diff(austres, lag = 12, differences = 1)

plot(seasonal)
```

[image]

```
d.seasonal <- diff(seasonal, differences = 2)

plot(d.seasonal)
```

[image]

Now you've made stationary the seasonal component of the time series.